# symmetrization and invariants

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, mp.mathematical-physics, lie-superalgebras

Let $V$ be a supervector space over $\mathbb C$ and let $T^n(V):=V \otimes V \otimes \cdots \otimes V$ and let $S^n(V)$ be the super vectorspace of symmetric tensors. Then we have a cannonical surjection from $$T^n(V) \rightarrow S^n(V)$$ by the super-symmetrization map given by $$v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n \mapsto \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} (-1)^{sgn(\sigma)}v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{\sigma(n)}$$ where $sgn(\sigma)$ is the sign obtained when $\sigma$ acts on $v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n$.

Now $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ acts on $T^n(V)$ by a signed derivation:

$x.(v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k)= x.v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k +
  (-1)^{|x||v_1|}v_1 \otimes x.v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k+ \cdots +(-1)^{|x|(|v_1|+|v_2|+\cdots +|v_{k-1}|)}v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes x.v_k,$

where $x \in \mathfrak g$ and $v_j \in V_j$ are $\mathbb Z_2$-homogeneous elements of degrees $|x|$ and $|v_j|$ respectively.

It is known that the Lie superalgebra $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is not reductive. Is it still true that the induced map on the invariants $T^n(V)^{\mathfrak{gl}(V)} \rightarrow S^n(V)^{\mathfrak{gl}(V)}$ is surjective ?

Comment: The super-symmetrization map is idempotent and comes with an obvious reverse embedding $S^n(V) \to T^n(V)$ (just an inclusion, really). Doesn't that automatically give you the desired surjectivity?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what to elaborate. If you see the obvious inclusion $S^n(V) \subset T^n(V)$ the rest should be straightforward, unless I'm missing something.